# Selenium: How to use ByChained Class in C#?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I have  two questions

Selenium: How to use ByChained Class in C#?

is there a way to give multiple identification property like class and innertext to identify an element in pageobject and pagefactory model?

Comment: Check this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381173/how-seleniums-bychained-class-really-works) for ByChained.

Answer (score 0):

WatiR (using Ruby) allows you find an element based on multiple attributes as easy as this (you can even use regular expressions e.g. /button/):

```
browser.element(:class => 'button', :text => 'Apply')
```

But in C# I was only able to do it using FindElements, like this:

```
var elements = Driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("button"));
var element = elements.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Text == "Apply");
```