# How Selenium's ByChained class really works?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am very confused with what the [documentation for ByChained class](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/ByChained.html) mentions. It says:

> > Mechanism used to locate elements within a document using a series of other lookups. This class will find all DOM elements that matches
> >     each of the locators in sequence, e.g.  driver.findElements(new
> >     ByChained(by1, by2))   will find all elements that match by2 and
> >     appear under an element that matches by1.

There is also an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1831#c1) for selenium on code.google.com, raised for ByChained class where someone has commented saying it's meant to be used to find element/elements using several locators.
I don't get it. Why should by1 and by2 be locators of two different elements? When I initally came across this class I felt that it will help in locating element(s) by using different locators. So that if one locator does not work, the next would work. But when I practically used this class it behaved very weirdly and threw NoSuchElementException all the time.

For example, if my html is:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="details">
      <input id="firstName" class="personName" type="text"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to find the input field by using two locators in ByChained:
1. using `By.id("firstName")`
2. using `By.className("personName")`

So my code becomes:

```
By myBy = new ByChained(By.id("firstName"),By.className("personName"));
driver.findElement(myBy);
```

On execution, I got NoSuchElementException. I was expecting that if my first By did not work, then it will find the element with the next By in the series.

Can someone please explain how this class works with an example and in which scenarios it could be used?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What this class does is allow you to locate an element using its heirarchy in the dom.

lets say for some reason you have the following html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="details">
            <input id="firstName" class="personName" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <input id="firstName" class="personName" type="text"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

and you want to get the element that is between the div rather than the one on its own. You can use the ByChained by to specify that you want that element by doing the following:

```
new ByChained(By.id("details"),By.id("firstName"));
```

What happens is that it finds the first element then searches underneath that in the dom heirarchy for the selector that comes next in the list. Basically this By is just a nice clean way of no longer having to do the following:

```
details = driver.findElement(By.id("details"));
input = details.findElement(By.id("firstName"));
```

Comment: This class would be really useful if you prefer cssSelector but need an xpath to find a starting point, then you can pass a By.xpath as the  first argument and a By.cssSelector as the second argument.  I already do that sometimes because css cannot traverse upwards in the DOM like xpath can.

Comment: Also, you can use CSS to find an element, but since CSS doesn't allow you to travel back up a tree, switch to XPath as needed.  This probably represents bad design in the target DOM, but sometimes (as a tester) you have to deal with it.

Answer (score 8):

Your request would be satisfied by something that could be called `ByAny` which would return elements that match any of the passed `By` arguments. There's no such class AFAIK.

However, [`ByChained`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/ByChained.html) works differently. It finds the elements that are matched by the first argument, then searches their descendants using the second argument etc. So, if you had HTMl like this:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="details">
            <input id="firstName" class="personName" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div id="notDetails">
            <input id="secondName" class="personName" type="text"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and you wanted to find the `class=personName` element under `id=details`, you could either use a CSS selector, an XPath expression, or the

```java
new ByChained(By.id("details"), By.className("personName"))
```

---

Note that there also is a [`ByAll`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/ByAll.html) class that searches for elements matched by all of the `By` arguments passed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Makes sense now. I wish if SO allowed to accept multiple answers I would have accepted your answer as well!

Comment: having trouble getting the ByAll to show up in c#? what version was this added at? Is there a namespace i'm missing?

Comment: @FerrousOxide I don't know, sorry. Maybe it's not part of C#'s API. It's been in the Java API for more than a year, though, for sure.

Comment: If you want to find all elements that match two Xpath, you can do ( xpath | xpath ) as an xpath. So there's that. 

The result of a By is a List of WebElement, so you should be able to just List.addAll(List) a second result to a first result to get a combination of both.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably important to note (because I never see anyone mention this) that ByChained should be used just like any other `By` locator, like so:

```
driver.findElements( new ByChained(By.id("details"), By.className("personName")) )
```

or

```
driver.findElements( new ByAll(By.id("err1"), By.className("errBox")) )
```

Comment: ByChained extends the By class so that you can do `By sel = new ByChained(By ... bys)`