# How to find nested elements by class in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a div inside a div inside another div. Most outer div class is "Big Div", inside it there is a div with class "Medium Div" and the most inner div class is "Small Div".

I'm able to see the div's classes when I press the F12 key and hover over the elements, however I can't find them using Selenium.

What am I doing wrong?

```
WebElement big = browser.findElement(By.cssSelector("//div[contains(@class,'Big')]"));
WebElement medium = big.findElement(By.cssSelector("//div[contains(@class,'Medium')"));
WebElement small = medium.findElement(By.cssSelector("//div[contains(@class,'Small'"));
```

Note: my classes contain white spaces, Selenium can't find any of the divs and I get the exception: "No Such element".

Comment: can help only if there is html source to verify.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax you have used that is not for `cssSelector` that for `XPATH` and you have missed parenthesis as well.

Try following xpath now.

```
WebElement big = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'Big')]"));
WebElement medium = big.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'Medium')]"));
WebElement small = medium.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'Small')]"));
```

However you can do it in once like.

```
WebElement small = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'Big')]//div[contains(@class,'Medium')]//div[contains(@class,'Small')]"));
```

Comment: I switched to By.xpath and added the missing parenthesis. It still doesn't work

Comment: @TalAngel : You need to post HTML then and mentioned your expected output as well?

Comment: My HTML elements have the attributes like my question says they have. I am able to see the classes using the developer tool but not to find them via Selenium. Posting my HTML will not give any value to anyone.

Comment: Well.Check if there any `iframe` avaialble ?

Comment: What is iframe? How to check if they available?

Comment: Well go to developer tool  do ctrl+f and search `iframe` .

Comment: Yes, the elements are indeed inside an iframe. What to do now please?

Comment: You can do `driver.switch_to_frame(name attribute of iframe);` to get WebDriver looking inside the iframe.

Comment: @TalAngel :  You need to switch to `browser.switchTo().frame("Name or ID of the frame")`  or post the html of iframe to get better answser?

Comment: The `.` saved me but I don't understand it. It stands for `self` while `//` is `descendant-or-self` which already includes `self`. Why additional `.`  is needed?

Answer (score 3):

Brackets are missing in the locator:

```
WebElement big = browser.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class*='Big']"));
WebElement medium = big.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class*='Medium']"));
WebElement small = medium.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class*='Small')]"));
```

Comment: There is also a mistake with `By.cssSelector` -- the poster should use `By.XPath` with the `//div` notation.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add a few lines to the answer of @KunduK

```
WebElement small = browser.findElement(new ByChained(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'Big')]"),By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'Medium')]"),By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'Small')]")));
```

### When selenium already gives a few extra implementations, then why not to use it. :-)

You can get more details from the below link:

[How Selenium's ByChained class really works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381173/how-seleniums-bychained-class-really-works)

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/selenium-classes-stabilize-ui-automation-code-durga-behera/

Answer (score 2):

There is syntactical errors in placing parenthesis and the locator type used.
Try below code,

```
WebElement big = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'Big')]"));
WebElement medium = big.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'Medium')]"));
WebElement small = medium.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'Small')]"));
```